# Linux-image-3.2.0.4-amd64 vs linux-image-amd64

Tags: debian, kernel

Installing Debian I have to choose between the kernels

- `linux-image-3.2.0.4-amd64`
- `linux-image-amd64`

What's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to  [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/metapackage)  the package `linux-image-amd64` is a metapackage meaning it does not exist but represent a set of package.
In fact installing this package is the same as installing the last kernel available for `amd64` architecture.

If you install `Linux-image-3.2.0.4-amd64` and this package is the only one available for your system then both package will represent the same thing.

If Debian uses metapackage it's to avoid the needs of knowing the exact correct version of each package you want to install.

Comment: So if I don't want to stick with `linux-image-3.2.0.4-amd64`, choosing `linux-image-amd64` would always update if never build are available in repo?

Comment: that's indeed the purpose

Comment: So in generall you want to choose `linux-image-amd64`.

Comment: "installing this package is the same as installing the last kernel available for amd64". I assume "last" here means the version with the highest version number. This is not precisely correct. The package that will be installed will be determined by the priority number.

Comment: @faheemmitha i'd be glad to know more about that